# Creating a multidimensional array in AutoHotKey that is updated according to user inputs

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, global-variables, autohotkey

#### General problem

In AutoHotKey, I'm having a hard time appending values to an `Array` object that starts off empty and then gets filled up with values as the user performs certain actions.

#### The script

Copied below is a small reproducible version of my script. In it, the goal is for the `NumpadAdd` key to add the current mouse position to the `Array` called `list_of_mouse_positions`. After adding a few points, the user can use the `Numpad0` key to look at the list of positions stored thus far.

```
;---------------;
; GENERAL SETUP ;
;---------------;

coordmode Mouse, screen

; Creates an empty array. This will store the mouse positions.
list_of_mouse_positions := Array()

;-----------;
; FUNCTIONS ;
;-----------;

; Function used to add the current mouse position to the global
; list of mouse positions. The `x` parameter serves no purpose.
AddLocation(x)
{
    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
    mouse_pos := Array()
    mouse_pos[1] := xpos
    mouse_pos[2] := ypos
    list_of_mouse_positions.Push(mouse_pos)
}

;-------------;
; KEYBINDINGS ;
;-------------;

; Adds the current mouse position to the 
NumpadAdd::
    AddLocation(0)
    return

; Checking the mouse positions stored so far
NumPad0::
    MsgBox, %list_of_mouse_positions%
    return
```

#### Expected Output vs Actual Output

After running the script and hitting the `NumpadAdd` key to capture a couple of coordinates, I hit the `Numpad0` key. What I expected to show up was a Message Box containing all of the coordinates. However, what showed up instead was just an empty message box.

#### Specific question

How can I update an `Array` object (in my case, the `list_of_mouse_positions` variable) by appending new rows to it, each one of which stores two new values?

#### Note about the expected dimensions of `list_of_mouse_positions`

I expect the `list_of_mouse_positions` variable to be a multidimensional array of dimensions `(n x 2)`, where the first column contains all of the x values, and the second column contains all of the y values.

For example, suppose the user "captured" the coordinates of the following mouse positions:

- (100, 200)
- (400, 100)
- (600, 150)

In this case, the structure of the `list_of_mouse_positions` would be as follows:

```
list_of_mouse_positions[1,1] = 100
list_of_mouse_positions[1,2] = 200
list_of_mouse_positions[2,1] = 400
list_of_mouse_positions[2,2] = 100
list_of_mouse_positions[3,1] = 600
list_of_mouse_positions[3,2] = 150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Corrected code to match your new code, but with super-global edit  (see doc quote below)

> Super-global variables [v1.1.05+]: If a global declaration appears outside of any function, it takes effect for all functions by default (excluding force-local functions). This avoids the need to redeclare the variable in each function. However, if a function parameter or local variable with the same name is declared, it takes precedence over the global variable. Variables created by the class keyword are also super-global.

with some included comments on your code with regards to simplicity you may want to do, or not as you desire:

```
;---------------;
; GENERAL SETUP ;
;---------------;
; Setting the coordinate mode
coordmode Mouse, screen

; This variable will store the mouse positions. 
; The command below establishes that it is a global variable. 
; Initializes the global variables
Global list_of_mouse_positions := Array()
Return ; end auto-execute section of script


;-----------;
; FUNCTIONS ;
;-----------;


; Adds the current mouse position to an array of mouse positions
AddLocation()
{
    ; global list_of_mouse_positions ; not needed, declared super-global above.
    MouseGetPos, xpos, ypos
    mouse_pos := Array() ; not needed see below
    mouse_pos.Push(xpos) ; not needed see below
    mouse_pos.Push(ypos) ; not needed see below
    list_of_mouse_positions.Push(mouse_pos)
    ; instead of making 3 additonal lines you can just do 'list_of_mouse_positions.Push(Array(xpos, ypos))'
    return
}

; Prints 2D arrays
print2DArr(byRef Arr, setDelim="`r`n", valDelim=", ") 
{
    printText := ""
    For _, Row in Arr 
    {
        printText .= (printText ? setDelim : "") . print1DArr(Row, valDelim)
    }
    Return printText
}

; Prints 1D arrays
print1DArr(byRef Array, valDelim=", ") 
{
    printText := ""
    For _, Val in Array 
    {
        printText .= (printText ? valDelim : "") . Val
    }
    Return printText
}

;-------------;
; KEYBINDINGS ;
;-------------;
; Adds new positions to the list of mouse positions
NumpadAdd::
    AddLocation()
    return

; Checking the mouse positions stored so far
NumPad0::
    global list_of_mouse_positions
    MsgBox % print2DArr(list_of_mouse_positions)
    return
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the response! You were right, the issue was that I wasn't defining the variable as a global variable in the main body of the script or in any of the functions. One other thing that needed to be done was to actually initialize the global variable at least once with a hotkey call. It's also worth mentioning that the script you provided has a few mistakes and won't print correctly. If you can edit your answer, I'll be happy to accept it!

Comment: There, I've added the full code for what needs to be done [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72870349/8667016). If you want, you can just copy the contents of that message and paste it in yours. If you choose to do that, I can delete my own answer and upvote yours =)

Comment: Awesome, thanks! For some reason, I hadn't gotten the global declaration with `:= Array()` to work when I originally posted this question. Happy to see this works!!! Again, thanks for the insights here =)